# Send information from elementor form to database with the code snippets

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-shortcode

i am trying to send elementorpro form data to mysql database. the code i am using here is

```
add_action( 'elementor_pro/forms/record', function( $record, $ajax_handler ) {
$raw_fields = $record->get( 'fields' );
$fields = [];
foreach ( $raw_fields as $id => $field ) {
$fields[ $id ] = $field['value'];
}
global $wpdb;
$output['success'] = $wpdb->insert('tigers_match', array( 'league' => $fields['league'], 'day' => $fields['day']));
$ajax_handler->add_response_data( true, $output );
}, 10, 2);
var_dump('$fields ');
```

but data is not passing into mysql database. I successfully fetched data from mysql  with some raw php code.
do i need additional plugins to send elementor form data to database ?
I am trying to use less plugins for my site

table name:

[image]

table fields:

[image]

form fields name same as DB table

Comment: Why does `var_dump('$fields ');` have a space?

Comment: i fixed it , perhaps i missed it while typing !tankx